# dojox.grid.DataGrid How to add an input field and restrict input size

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am looking to add an input field into dojo data grid. I looked around but 
couldn't find it.

The only way i could make it work is by making the cell editable.

That makes that cell behave as an input field, but how can I restrict
how much text or characters can be entered say i want to restrict
that cell to only hold 20 characters. How can i do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

First, `dojox.grid.DataGrid` is old and may deprecate in the future. Dojo developers suggest using `dgrid` or `gridx` instead. See [this ticket](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/13974)

Back to DataGrid, here is what you can try to create an input field:

```
{
    field      : 'fieldName',
    name       : "labelName",
    editable   : true,
    type       : dojox.grid.cells._Widget,
    formatter  : function(){
       return new dijit.form.ValidateTextBox({  //or any kind of Textbox you want
            // put any customize at here  
       });
    }
}
```

By using formatter, you can use any kind of dijit at here.